# Converting DatePicker Date to UTC Format returns NULL

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter

I have 4 UITextfileds, start date, start time and end date, end time. Then I'm sending my date and time into my UTC function, but it's returning null.

```
NSString *str1 = _startDateField.text;
str1 = [str1 stringByAppendingString:@" "];
str1 = [str1 stringByAppendingString:_startTimeField.text];
NSLog(@"str1 : %@", str1);
NSString *str2 = _endDateField.text;
str2 = [str2 stringByAppendingString:@" "];
str2 = [str2 stringByAppendingString:_endTimeField.text];
NSLog(@"str2 : %@", str2);
// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm"];
NSDate *date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:str1];
NSDate *date2 = [dateFormat dateFromString:str2];
NSLog(@"%@", date1);
NSLog(@"%@", date2);
NSString *startTime = [self getUTCFormateDate:date1];
NSString *endTime = [self getUTCFormateDate:date2];
NSLog(@"str1 : %@", startTime);
NSLog(@"str2 : %@", endTime);
```

**Coverting to `UTC` format:**

```
-(NSString *)getUTCFormateDate:(NSDate *)localDate {
    NSLog(@"%@", localDate);
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:localDate];
    NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
    return dateString;
}
```

I want to read the date and time from my text fields and convert them into UTC format.

Comment: show your input date string

Comment: My input date string is like "26-Nov-2019 10:34"

Comment: show your `NSLog(@"str1 : %@", str1); and NSLog(@"str1 : %@", str1)`

Comment: Start Date: 26-Nov-2019 Star time : 10:35 , end Date : 26-Nov-2019, end Time: 11:59

Comment: what is the output you expect

Comment: I want to send Current  UTC time

Comment: Based on user input i want to send current UTC date and time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is fine and correct, I added the defaultTimeZone for get the time zone and subtract the time to utc time. I got the output.

check this

```
NSString *str1 = @"26-Nov-2019";
str1 = [str1 stringByAppendingString:@" "];
str1 = [str1 stringByAppendingString:@"9:35 am"];
NSLog(@"str1 : %@", str1);
NSString *str2 = @"26-Nov-2019";
str2 = [str2 stringByAppendingString:@" "];
str2 = [str2 stringByAppendingString:@"11:59"];
NSLog(@"str2 : %@", str2);

// Convert string to date object
NSDate *date1 = [self getUTCDate:str1];
NSDate *date2 = [self getUTCDate:str2];

NSLog(@"date1 %@", date1);
NSLog(@"date2 %@", date2);

NSString *startTime = [self getUTCFormateDate:date1];
NSString *endTime = [self getUTCFormateDate:date2];
NSLog(@"str1 : %@", startTime);
NSLog(@"str2 : %@", endTime);


-(NSDate *)getUTCDate:(NSString *)currentDate {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm"];

    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:currentDate];
    if (date1 == nil) {
         [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a"];
         date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:currentDate];
    }
    return date1;
}

-(NSString *)getUTCFormateDate:(NSDate *)localDate {
    NSLog(@"%@", localDate);
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm"];
    NSLocale *twelveHourLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    dateFormatter.locale = twelveHourLocale;
    NSTimeInterval timeZoneoffset = [[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
    NSTimeInterval utcTimeInterval = [localDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - timeZoneoffset;
    NSDate *utcCurrentDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:utcTimeInterval];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:utcCurrentDate];
    NSLog(@"dateString %@", dateString);
    return dateString;
}
```

Comment: IT's getting, but the problem is end time hete time is 11:15AM and end time is: 9:15PM

Comment: @iOS - I unable to understand please elobrate.

Comment: when i send time with AM and PM it's not getting. How?

Comment: This is my complete start date time (26-Nov-2019     11:29 AM), end date abd time (26-Nov-2019       11:29 PM)

Comment: @iOS - oh, your time is 12 hour not 24 hour or else you need to handle both timing at the time

Comment: @iOS - is AM/PM comes in your string its 12 hour format

Comment: @iOS - give 2 mins

Comment: I added the `[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]` and check

Comment: Getting null here NSLog(@"date1 %@", date1);

Comment: if we add [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm a"]; is it ok

Comment: date1 (null) ,   date2 (null)

Comment: @iOS - give the moment

Comment: @iOS - I added the updated code `// Convert string to date object
     NSDate *date1 = [self getUTCDate:str1];
    NSDate *date2 = [self getUTCDate:str2];`, it supported for both dateformat

Comment: Hai Good morning bro, small changes in my requirement

Comment: My Start date and time: 27-Nov-2019 10:20 AM  End date and time: 27-Nov-2019 11:59 PM. I want the result in 24 hours formate. Start date (27-Nov-2019 10:20) end date (27-Nov-2019 23:59) like this....

Comment: @iOS - what happened